# Creating a textbox compliant for both IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, ip, version

As regex could be not the optimal solution for validating the IP addresses, as my need would be to validate for both IPv4 and IPv6. Is there a solution that already addresses the support of input of IPv4 as well as IPv6.

Comment: _"I want to"_ - so what stops you from doing so? What ready-made solutions have you found? Are you trying to implement your own? Any problems you ran into? Or do you expect us to search or program a solution for you?

Comment: Your question still only describes what you want. Please show what _you_ have tried.

Comment: I searched for solutions that are already serving the purpose but couldn't find one that suits. So wanted to check if anyone came across such stuff so I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal TextBox supports the input of both IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses as well as any other text. If you're looking for a control that accepts *only* IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses -- don't do this.

IP addresses (and in particular IPv6 addresses) are seldom entered from scratch. Most of the time they are copied from somewhere else and are not necessarily in the right format. If the address is not in the right format, the user often cannot change it in the place where it's copied from -- the user needs to be able to paste it into the TextBox and edit it there. This is not possible if the TextBox does not accept invalid input.

Solution: use a normal TextBox and validate the input when the user clicks the Submit/Next/OK button.

Comment: Also, as a handy tip, the `IPAddress` class has a `TryParse` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a look at the following two projects, you should find these extremely useful:

http://code.google.com/p/ipaddresscontrollib/

https://code.google.com/p/flexfieldcontrollib/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But is there a control that supports both the version?